# Spring boot css not loading

Tags: spring-boot

Good day. I've read numerous posts on this problem but non seem to help.
My `css` file is located `resources/static/css/` in `jokes-web`

**Folder structure**

[image]

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hi</title>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also tried to clear cache by adding this to `application.properties`

```
#spring.web.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.enabled=true
#spring.web.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.paths=/**
#spring.web.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.version=v12
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server fixed the issue for some reason